# Push text to array then append to div - displaying text in div twice in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Using mouseup, I'm appending multiple values into an array.

```
var myArray = [];
$("#button").mouseup(function() {       

  myArray.push("&nbsp;play contact sports");

]);
```

Then appending to a div using another button

```
$("#button2").mouseup(function() {      

  $('#output').append(myArray+'');

]);
```

It works fine in all browsers APART from IE8 where the text push after one click is display TWICE.

```
play contact sports play contact sports
```

There is no comma. Does anybody know what the cause might be? Or an alternative that might work?

Comment: Are the buttons nested? Perhaps the event is bubbling up. Try event.stopPropagation() to prevent this. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you want it to do, but I'd wrap each text node you're appending with an element and be more explicit about your array-to-string conversion. Also in your click handler ensure the event is stopped:

```
$("#button2").mouseup( function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
   $('<p></p>').html( myArray.join(',') ).appendTo('#output');
   return false;
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but unfortunately it simply wrapped both instances inside a p tag. Here's what I'm trying to do - on click, add some text into an array. Then, when another button is clicked, output the contents of that array into a div to display on the screen. As I said - it works perfectly in all browsers instead of IE8!

Comment: ok, then separate events must be firing twice. as opposed to the event handler running twice. Try using the `click` event instead of `mouseup`

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately I tried that initially - then tried the .one() handler, and still no joy, I'm afraid.

Comment: I suggest you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see your error.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/VtZ66/embedded/result/ You must be doing something different with your HTML structure.

Comment: Ahh thanks again - my JS file is 348kb, do you think that could be the issue? It's pretty functional-heavy.